# sharing an object with multiple classes

Tags: c++

I have 3 classes namely Board, Game, and AI

i want to have the object chessBoard of Board class to be use by Game and AI, and also by the Board Class. I want them to access that single chessBoard object (sharing)

problem is, it gives me the infamous fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found. Also, there are Board.h,Game.h and AI.h (only declarations in them), and i also have their corresponding .cpp files. Each .h files have guards included (#ifndef _XXXXXX_H_)

I tried to include Board chessBoard inside Board.h file (just below the class), and it seems guards are not working.

```
Error   7   error LNK2005: "class Board chessBoard" (?chessBoard@@3VBoard@@A)     already defined in AI.obj C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CHESSv3\CHESSv3\Board.obj   CHESSv3
Error   8   error LNK2005: "class Board chessBoard" (?chessBoard@@3VBoard@@A)     already defined in AI.obj C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CHESSv3\CHESSv3\Game.obj   CHESSv3
Error   9   error LNK2005: "class Board chessBoard" (?chessBoard@@3VBoard@@A) already defined in AI.obj C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CHESSv3\CHESSv3\ProgramEntryPoint.obj  CHESSv3
```

AI.h

```
#ifndef _AI_H_
#define _AI_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    string position;
    string nextPosition;
    float score;
    int level;
    float totalscore;
    node* up;
    node* right;
    node* left;
    bool approved;
    string move;
};

class AI {
private:
    //string board;
    //string board[8][8];
    int score1;
    int maxscore;
    int totalscore;
public: 
    void GetBoard(string[][8]);
    void AnalyzeMyPositions();
    void ExecuteAdvanceHeuristicMove();
};

#endif
```

Game.h

```
#ifndef _GAME_H_
#define _GAME_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Game {
public:
    char WhosTurn();
    bool Playable();
    bool GetMoveFromPlayer();
    void TurnOver();
    Game();
private:
    char turn;
};

#endif
```

Board.h

```
#ifndef _BOARD_H_
#define _BOARD_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Board {
public:
    bool SquareChecker(string);
    bool MoveChecker(string);
    Board();
    void PrintBoard();
    int Execute(string);
    void UnExecute();
    string CB[8][8];
private:
    char turn;
    vector<string> BoardRecord;
    stack<string> CBR;
    //string CB[8][8];
};

Board chessBoard;

#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you need to make the declaration of the object `extern` in the header Board.h:

```
extern Board chessBoard;
```

You then provide a declaration in Board.cpp:

```
Board chessBoard;
```

Much better, though would be to create it in enclosing code and pass it (by reference) to the constructors of the other classes.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern which can achieved in the following way:

```
// Board.h
class Board {
  private:
    static instance_;

  public:
    static Board *instance();
}

// Board.cpp

Board *Board::instance_ = NULL;

Board *Board::instance() {
  if (!instance_)
    instance_ = new Board();

  return instance_;
}
```

Mind that this pattern can either be seen as good or bad, if you don't like using it you should consider passing the reference of an instantiated `Board` class to all the requiring ones and keep it stored in each object as an instance variable. Something like:

```
Game::Game() {
  this->board = new Board();
  this->ai = new AI(board);
  // or better this->ai = new AI(this) so AI can access all game methods
}
```

Comment: Why `new`, and why all this code? A `static` instance would do the trick, wouldn't it? And it'd be clean, too.

Comment: You could use just a static variable too but you would need to expose the singleton instance or have it outside a class so it would be less encapsulated. Then it's a matter of taste and how much people work together with you with your code. I don't want to allow things like `Board::instance_ = NULL` in a collaborative environment, don't you think? :)

Comment: Typically it's like this: `Foo & getInstance() { static Foo impl; return impl; }` (This can be a static class function if you prefer.) That way the global variable isn't dynamic, and it's always initialized properly before first use.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be that there could be 3 different chessBoard definitions because you might be adding 3 different #include "Board.h". Please make only a single object at a place where you have more control rather than creating it globally inside Board.h

Did you try it like this? Include the necessary include declarations only in the .cpp files.

```
//Board.h

class Board {};

//Game.h

class Board;
class Game {
    Board* myBoard;

public:
    void setBoard(Board*);
};

//AI.h
class Board;
class AI {
    Board* myBoard;

public:
    void setBoard(Board*);
};

void main() {
    Board chessBoard;
    Game g;
    g.setBoard(&chessBoard);

    AI ai;
    ai.setBoard(&chessBoard);
}
```